No DesignTimeAgent found for project
I am using gmail account for google cloud dialogue flow chat api but gives error
'No DesignTimeAgent found for project'.and also the error in agent console when click on Publish>>All Integretions
'Insufficient permissions to read from Google Chat. The caller must be a Workplace user with sufficient IAM permissions to configure the project's Google Chat API'.
Explain the reasons for this and how to resolve this.
Give solution for above and can i use gmail account instead of workspace account?
